# Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} n (1 - \mathrm{e}^{t/n})$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone help how to compute (step-by-step) the following limit? When I use the online calculator, the answer is -t. However, I do not know how to get that answer.

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n (1 - \mathrm{e}^{t/n})
$$

Thanks

Comment: All the hints are very useful. I finally understood the method to do by replacing the new variable, such as y = 1/n in the equation. Then, I did one time L^Hopital's Rule. Finally I got -t.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Recall
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^{ax}-1}x =a$$

Comment: As we continue to chat here, it is no longer true that only one user has downvoted you more than 5 times. I think that people are reacting badly to your comments about downvoters - though it's hard to say.

Comment: @mixedmath Yes, so all the more reason for the down-votes to be removed.

Comment: @mixedmath Thanks for removing the comment on my post, now time for the down-votes to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

**hint:** you can use the Taylor series

> $$ e^{t/n} = 1+\frac{t}{n}+\dots \,. $$